# Intersection points of two curves

Tags: polar-coordinates, curves

I have a curve given in polar coordinates with ($r = 2 +2\sin\theta$ for example)  and one equation of simple circle (for example $x^{2}+y^{2} = 9 $).How can i find intersection points?Since X Co-ordinate of the curve in polar coordinate is $x = r\cos\theta$ and for y, $y= r\sin\theta$, can someone give me a tip how do i find there intersection points? i have three equation.

Comment: Turn the circle into a polar representation.  Then equate the two curves.  The solution from there is rather simple.

Comment: In that case i can easily find $r = 3$  and then if i am not wrong i have to set it equal to first equation $2 + 2\sin\theta$ = $3$  and solve it?

Comment: You will get two solutions, meaning the curves should intersect twice.